# a sequence limit with sine function

Tags: limits

Here is a sequence limit:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum ^{n}_{i=0}\sin \dfrac {1}{2^{i}}$$
It can be proved that the limit exists, but I can't calculate it exactly.

Comment: And what's the question?

Comment: It's obvious that the question is "What is the exact limit and how to calculate it". D

Comment: Are you looking for a closed form ? Any reason to think that one could exist ?

Comment: Inverse symbolic calculator found nothing on 0.9764577364706682... Are you sure there is a closed form?

Comment: I don't know the answer

Comment: **[this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Bsum+sin++%281%2F2%5Ek%29+from+k%3D0+to+infty%5D)** might help

Comment: @Aditya It said that the ratio test is inconclusive. How did it get that idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say

$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sin \frac {1}{2^{i}}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sin \frac {1}{2^{i}}=\sin \frac{1}{2^0}+\sin \frac{1}{2^1}+\sin \frac{1}{2^2}+\sin \frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots$

$\sin \frac{1}{2^0}=\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{5!}-\frac{1}{7!}+\cdots$

$\sin \frac{1}{2^1}=\frac{1}{2^11!}-\frac{1}{2^33!}+\frac{1}{2^55!}-\frac{1}{2^77!}+\cdots$

$\sin \frac{1}{2^2}=\frac{1}{2^21!}-\frac{1}{2^63!}+\frac{1}{2^{10}5!}-\frac{1}{2^{14}7!}+\cdots$

$\cdots$

sum $=\frac{1}{1!}(1+\frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdots )-\frac{1}{3!}(1+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{2^6}+\cdots)+\frac{1}{5!}(1+\frac{1}{2^5}+\frac{1}{2^{10}}+\cdots)+\cdots=$

$=\frac{1}{1!}\cdot 2-\frac{1}{3!}\cdot\frac{8}{7}+\frac{1}{5!}\cdot \frac{32}{31}+\cdots=\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}(-1)^i\frac{1}{(2i+1)!}\frac{2^{2i+1}}{2^{2i+1}-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)!\left(1-2^{-(2i+1)}\right)}$

and e.g.

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{9}\frac{(-1)^i}{(2i+1)!\left(1-2^{-(2i+1)}\right)}\doteq 1.817928721$

Comment: Well done and nice final formula ! I did not find the value of the sum for an infinite value of $n$. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if a closed form expression exist.

What you can do is to expand $\sin(x)$ as a Taylor series built at $x=0$, replace $x=\frac{1}{2^i}$ and sum over $i$. You then have a series of geometric series to sum. For example, using a development to the nineth order, you have to compute $$S_9=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\Big(-\frac{2^{-11 i-8}}{155925}+\frac{2^{-9 i-7}}{2835}-\frac{1}{315} 2^{-7
   i-4}+\frac{1}{15} 2^{-5 i-3}-\frac{1}{3} 2^{-3 i-1}+2^{-i}\Big)$$ which is $$S_9=\frac{1167338371295774}{642125490254325}\approx 1.81792872111872$$

Comment: Using a calculator to evaluate the original sequence will get an approximation too.

Comment: I totally agree. As I said, I do not think that a closed form exists. Expanding and summing is the closest I found.

Comment: By the end, I don't agree !! To arrive to a relative error lower than $10^{-6}$, you need to add at least 20 terms. With this expansion, with four terms, it is obtained. Cheers :-)